# Specifying number of objects to serialize DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have this problem with serializing nasted objects in DRF. Let's say i have these classes:

```
class RecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = [..some fields]

class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    record = RecordSerializer(many=True, read_only)

    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = [..some fields, 'record']
```

This gives me serialized data of List with every record that is related to it. How do i specify a number of records that i want to serialize with nasted objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not the most elegant, but if you're just displaying a `SerializerMethodField` is an easy if you need to collect a specific set of records.

```
class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    record = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_record(self, obj):
        records = Record.objects.filter(...)
        return RecordSerializer(records).data
```